How do I fix Cannot find module 'babel-preset-metro-react-native-babel-preset' error whenever I run npx expo start?
Every time I run npx expo start, I get this error and am unable to load my app:
error: node_modules/expo-router/entry.js: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-metro-react-native-babel-preset'
Require stack:
- /Users/oliviazhang/den_app/den/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js
- /Users/oliviazhang/den_app/den/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /Users/oliviazhang/den_app/den/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/oliviazhang/den_app/den/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/transform-worker/metro-transform-worker.js
- /Users/oliviazhang/den_app/den/node_modules/@expo/metro-config/build/transform-worker/transform-worker.js
- /Users/oliviazhang/den_app/den/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Worker.flow.js
- /Users/oliviazhang/den_app/den/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Worker.js
- /Users/oliviazhang/den_app/den/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js
- If you want to resolve "metro-react-native-babel-preset", use "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"

Make sure that all the Babel plugins and presets you are using
are defined as dependencies or devDependencies in your package.json
file. It's possible that the missing plugin is loaded by a preset
you are using that forgot to add the plugin to its dependencies: you
can workaround this problem by explicitly adding the missing package
to your top-level package.json.

Here is my package.json file:
{
  "name": "den",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "reset-project": "node ./scripts/reset-project.js",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "expo lint"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.24.8",
    "@clerk/clerk-expo": "^1.2.3",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.24.0",
    "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.5.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.1.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^20.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-three/drei": "^9.108.3",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^8.16.8",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.2",
    "domexception": "^4.0.0",
    "expo": "~51.0.17",
    "expo-av": "~14.0.6",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.7",
    "expo-gl": "~14.0.2",
    "expo-haptics": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.17",
    "expo-secure-store": "^13.0.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.6",
    "expo-three": "^2.2.1",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "firebase": "^10.12.3",
    "glob": "^11.0.0",
    "querystring": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.2",
    "react-native-3d-model-view": "^1.2.0",
    "react-native-animated-circular-progress": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-gl-model-view": "^1.6.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.8.3",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.2.0",
    "react-native-track-player": "^4.1.1",
    "react-native-video": "^6.4.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
    "rimraf": "^6.0.1",
    "text-encoding": "^0.7.0",
    "three": "^0.166.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-private-property-in-object": "^7.24.7",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.7",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/node": "^20.14.10",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~51.0.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

Here is my babel.config.js file:
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo', 'metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  };
};

I've tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstalling, reinstalling dependencies, installing the missing preset, but nothing worked. Please help!

I believe you do not require the metro-react-native-babel-preset in your babel.config.js file. It should function fine with simply the babel-preset-expo because as far as I can tell expo already bundles the relevant react-native tooling.
